# assigning value to global variable in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using global variable in my `.cshtml` view as below-

```
@{
string canvasimage="";
}
```

Where I want to put some value in this using jquery-

```
<script>
    function GetData() {
        var image = $('#canvasoverdues canvas');
        var src = image[0].toDataURL("image/png");
        src = src.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        @canvasimage=src;
    };
</script>
```

and then want to use this global variable in anchor tag as below-

```
<a href="/PDF/Certificate/?filename="+@canvasimage+" id="canvasbutton" >convert to image</a>
```

But I get syntax error in using this global variable in script.

My question is how can we use this global variable and assign it a value.

If this is not possible kindly let me know how do I send value of function `GetData()` into parameter named `filename` in anchor?

Comment: jQuery *client-side JavaScript code* cannot see *server-side C# code*! You can push values into JS script, but not back to C#.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **c#** variable inside **javascript** code as javascript is client side and c# is server side code,you have to set the **href** of anchor tag via jquery like this:

```
<script>
    function GetData() {
        var image = $('#canvasoverdues canvas');
        var src = image[0].toDataURL("image/png");
        src = src.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
        $("#canvasbutton").attr("href","/PDF/Certificate/?filename="+src);
    };
</script>
```

If your html is like this:

```
<a href="/PDF/Certificate/?filename=" id="canvasbutton" >convert to image</a>
```

then:

```
<script>
        function GetData() {
            var image = $('#canvasoverdues canvas');
            var src = image[0].toDataURL("image/png");
            src = src.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
            var temp = $("#canvasbutton").attr("href") + src;
            $("#canvasbutton").attr("href",temp);
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access that anchor element in the `GetData()` method.

```
function GetData() {
    var image = $('#canvasoverdues canvas');
    var src = image[0].toDataURL("image/png");
    src = src.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    $("#anchorID").attr("href", $("#anchorID").attr("href") + "?filename=" + src);
}
```